# Updating lower and upper bounds in Optimization Problems

Tags: r, optimization, nlp

I was using the NLoptr package for solving an optimization problem of a 9 variables cost function using the program as:

```
function(x){return( list( "objective" = 0.0404*x[1]^2 + 4.4823*x[1] + 0.4762+0.024*x[2]^2 + 3.9767*x[2] + 0.3737+0.0246*x[3]^2 + 3.6992*x[3] + 0.9425+0.0214*x[4]^2 + 3.5896*x[4] + 0.7615+0.0266*x[5]^2 + 3.8197*x[5] + 0.2799+0.0262*x[6]^2 + 3.7884*x[6] + 0.307+0.0362*x[7]^2 + 4.4927*x[7] + 0.1549+0.0344*x[8]^2 + 4.4066*x[8] - 0.2472+0.0241*x[9]^2 + 4.227*x[9],"gradient" = c(2*0.0404*x[1]+4.4823, 2*0.024*x[2]+3.9767, 2*0.0246*x[3], 2*0.0214*x[4]+3.5896, 2*0.0266*x[5]+3.8197,2*0.0262*x[6]+3.7884,2*0.0362*x[7]+4.4927, 2*0.0344*x[8]+4.4066, 2*0.0241*x[9]+4.227)))}

function( x ) {
    constr <- c(x[1] + x[2]+ x[3] + x[4]+x[5]+x[6]+x[7]+x[8]+x[9]-Balance)
    grad <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
    return( list( "constraints"=constr, "jacobian"=grad ) )
}

lb<-c(50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50)
ub<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
x_0<-c(25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25)

local_opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_MMA","xtol_rel" = 1.0e-9 )
opts <- list( "algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG","xtol_rel" = 1.0e-9,"maxeval" = 10000, "local_opts" = local_opts )

res <- nloptr(x0=x_0, eval_f=eval_f,lb=lb,ub=ub,eval_g_eq=eval_g_eq,opts=opts)
```

The code works fine but the problem is that I need to solve this optimization for a period of 168h and each time step the lower bounds and upper bounds have to be different. Has anyone implemented this before?

BR

Comment: Not clear from from the question, but if the problems are independent you can just put a loop around it and use different bounds.

Comment: That is the issue, the problems are not independent. Each time step depends on the previous ones.

Comment: If the model is not forward looking you still can use a loop and solve one timestep at the time. Otherwise you need to solve as one big problem to deal with the simultaneity. Looks like you have a quadratic objective. If convex we can solve very large QP problems quite efficiently.

Comment: Hi Erwin, my problem is convex as the cost function of each machine (I am studying the sheduling of some machines in a factory) is a polynomial of order 2. The thing is that the lower and upper bounds change each time step and also the next step is depending of the previous one (because depending of the time that one unit has been off it becomes more expensive to turned on again).

Comment: If the bounds are "variable" just make them linear inequality constraints. QP solvers deal with this very efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest you to use OSQP for that. You can [download it from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osqp/). You can find an example for updating the problem vectors in the manual. I have rewritten it here:

```
library(Matrix)

# Define problem data in the form
# minimize      (1/2) x' P x + q' x
# subject to    l <= A x <= u
#
P <- Matrix(c(11., 0., 0., 0.), 2, 2, sparse = TRUE)
q <- c(3., 4.)
A <- Matrix(c(-1., 0., -1., 2., 3., 0., -1., -3., 5., 4.), 5, 2, sparse = TRUE)
u <- c(0., 0., -15., 100., 80)
l <- rep_len(-Inf, 5)
settings <- osqpSettings(verbose = FALSE)
model <- osqp(P, q, A, l, u, settings)

# Solve
res <- model$Solve()

# Get solution
x_opt <- res$x

# Define new vector
q_new <- c(10., 20.)

# Update model and solve again
model$Update(q = q_new)
res <- model$Solve()

# Get new solution
x_opt_new <- res$x
```

Disclamer: I am one of the OSQP authors.